# Tomcat stuck while deploying wars

Tags: java

Tomcat is stuck while deploying wars. We have two wars to be deployed outside of the webapps folder which is in work/Catalina/localhost folder. After deploying one war, tomcat is hung and no logs are written to tomcat.log

The same build is working on 3 other non-prod env's but not in 4th non-prod env. What do I need to check in this case?

In other env's:

```
ls work/Catalina/localhost
war1dir  ROOT  war2dir  x-tree
```

In the env which is failing:

```
ls work/Catalina/localhost
war1dir
```

In other env's:

```
May 22, 2019 4:06:18 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.

May 22, 2019 4:06:39 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
WARNING: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [7,434] milliseconds.

May 22, 2019 4:06:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
```

In the env which is failing:

```
May 22, 2019 3:51:59 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
```

No more logs are written after this.

Comment: Assuming your tomcat.log is the catalina log, have you tried upping your log levels to debug to see what it's doing when it gets stuck?

Comment: This one resolved. As the dependent app is down, this couldn't come up.